# check if a row in mysql exists

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in a mySQL database we'll call 'tbl' where the fields are:

```
id, userID, favorite, emailID
```

The id is auto incremental.  The userID stores an integer.  The favorite is either yes or no. The emailID stores an integer.

I am programing in PHP and would like to have one query used to query the database that checks if the userID and emailID combination exists.  If it does then update the favorite field with a yes or no value that comes from a form that is passed into the query dynamically.  If it does not exist then insert the combination into the database.

Therefore if I had:

```
<?php
$userID = 34;
$emailID = 395;
$favorite = "yes"; // could be yes or no.
```

I don't believe the query below is correct but gets the idea of what I am trying to do:

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT userID, favorite, emailID 
FROM tbl 
WHERE ((userID = '$userID')and(emailID = '$emailID')) 
INSERT INTO tbl (userID, favorite, emailID) VALUES ('$userID', '$favorite', '$emailID')
ELSE UPDATE tbl
SET favorite = '$favorite'
WHERE ((userID = '$userID')and(emailID = '$emailID'))
```

(please know that I know that entering values into a query like this is a security risk, this is only to help explain my question.)

What is the best way to write the query? Can it be written with one query?

Comment: Why you dont use a stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would drop the redundant `id` column and define the primary key as the combination of `(userID, emailID)`, which means you have exactly one record for each different combination of the two fields, which seems to be what you want. Then you can use the `REPLACE INTO` command, which is equivalent to an `INSERT` but deletes any existing record if the primary key matches.

Comment: So have two primary keys on the table?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: How so? It looks like the `favorite` column is intended to be overwritten with a new value each time a save occurs, which would be done by including it as a field in the REPLACE statement.

Comment: @Jason No, one primary key that references two columns. This is a standard feature of MySQL.

Comment: @grahamparks - thanks... changing the database and using the REPLACE INTO worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

It can't be written as a single query, because the primary key isn't the two columns you're looking for - it's the `id` column only.

If `userid` and `emailid` are unique pairs, they should be the primary key for the table -- not the `id` value.  ORMs typically prefer that a primary key be single column for making query construction easier but the approach suffers on performance.  Anything requiring more than one columns is generally referred to as a "composite" - primary key, unique constraint/index, foreign key, etc.

The ANSI means of doing this would be a MERGE statement, but MySQL doesn't support the syntax because it already has the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and `REPLACE INTO` to provide the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks.  I looked at the INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE... and noticed too that the key would cause some issues.  It looks like I will have to do it with more than one query.  Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it really simply in a single call - but sprocs are bad aren't they ??

```
drop procedure if exists insert_update_tbl;
delimiter #

create procedure insert_update_tbl
(
in p_userID int unsigned,
in p_emailID int unsigned,
out p_id int unsigned
)
proc_main:begin

    set p_id  = 0;

    if exists (select 1 from tbl where userID = p_userID and emailID = p_emailID) then
        update tbl set favorite = 1 where userID = p_userID and emailID = p_emailID;
        leave proc_main;
    end if;

    insert into tbl (userID, emailID, favorite) values (p_userID, p_emailID, 0);

    set p_id  = last_insert_id();

end proc_main #

delimiter ;
```

Comment: What if it is called simultaneously with same params?

Comment: you should be calling this within a transaction !! http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php